# Help with odd plyr/doSMP warning

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to run the example for doSMP posted [here](http://www.r-statistics.com/2010/09/using-the-plyr-1-2-package-parallel-processing-backend-with-windows/):

```
require(plyr) # make sure you have 1.2 or later installed
x <- seq_len(20)
wait <- function(i) Sys.sleep(0.1)
system.time(llply(x, wait))
require(doSMP)
workers <- startWorkers(2) # My computer has 2 cores
registerDoSMP(workers)
system.time(llply(x, wait, .parallel = TRUE))
```

and I get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’

2: <anonymous>: ... may be used in an incorrect context: ‘.fun(piece, ...)’
```

What do these warnings mean, and should I worry about them?

edit:

```
getRversion() = 2.12.2
packageDescription("plyr", fields="Version") = 1.4
packageDescription("doSMP", fields="Version") = 1.0-1
```

Comment: What are your R and plyr version? (`getRversion()` and `packageDescription("plyr", fields="Version")`)

Comment: @Marek: 2.12.2 and 1.4.  I edited my original post to reflect this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using windows?
I get the same error on linux.
And also the same error with doSNOW.

Then I tried with doMC instead of doSMP and it worked fine.

Comment: I get the same errors on both windows and a mac.  doMC works fine on the mac, but isn't supported by windows.  I think the author of the packages is working on a solution.

Comment: It turns out plyr only works with doMC, but the developer is working on it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588914/domc-vs-dosnow-vs-dosmp-vs-dompi-why-arent-the-various-parallel-backends-for-f/5621388#5621388