# R: combine same identifiers in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, one Identifier and column with names. Each Identifier is several times present in the column ID (see below).

```
 ID           Names
uc001aag.1  DKFZp686C24272
uc001aag.1  DQ786314
uc001aag.1  uc001aag.1
uc001aah.2  AK056232
uc001aah.2  FLJ00038
uc001aah.2  uc001aah.1
uc001aah.2  uc001aah.2
uc001aai.1  AY217347
```

Now I want to create a dataframe  like this:

```
 ID           Names
uc001aag.1  DKFZp686C24272 | DQ786314 | uc001aag.1
uc001aah.2  AK056232 | FLJ00038 | uc001aah.1 | uc001aah.2
uc001aai.1  AY217347
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aggregate is quite a fast one, but you can use an sapply solution to parallelize the code. This can easily be done on Windows using `snowfall` :

```
require(snowfall)
sfInit(parallel=TRUE,cpus=2)
sfExport("Data")

ID <- unique(Data$ID)
CombNames <- sfSapply(ID,function(i){
    paste(Data$Names[Data$ID==i],collapse=" | ")
})
data.frame(ID,CombNames)
sfStop()
```

The parallel version will give you an extra speedup, but the single sapply solution is actually slower than aggregate. Tapply is a bit faster, but can't be parallelized using snowfall. on my computer  :

```
n <- 3000
m <- 3
Data <- data.frame( ID = rep(1:n,m),
                    Names=rep(LETTERS[1:m],each=n))
 # using snowfall for parallel sapply    
 system.time({
   ID <- unique(Data$ID)
   CombNames <- sfSapply(ID,function(i){
     paste(Data$Names[Data$ID==i],collapse=" | ")
   })
   data.frame(ID,CombNames)
 }) 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    0.33 

 # using tapply
 system.time({
   CombNames <- tapply(Data$Names,Data$ID,paste,collapse=" | ")
   data.frame(ID=names(CombNames),CombNames)
 })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.44    0.00    0.44 

 # using aggregate
 system.time(
   aggregate(Names ~ ID, data=Data, FUN=paste, collapse=" | ")
 )
   user  system elapsed 
   0.47    0.00    0.47 

 # using the normal sapply
 system.time({
   ID <- unique(Data$ID)
   CombNames <- sapply(ID,function(i){
     paste(Data$Names[Data$ID==i],collapse=" | ")
   })
   data.frame(ID,CombNames)
 })
   user  system elapsed 
   0.75    0.00    0.75
```

---

**Note:**

For the record, the better sapply-solution would be :

```
CombNames <- sapply(split(Data$Names,Data$ID),paste,collapse=" | ")
data.frame(ID=names(CombNames),CombNames)
```

which is equivalent to tapply. But parallelizing this one is actually slower, as you have to move more data around within the `sfSapply`. The speed comes from copying the dataset to every cpu. This is what you have to keep in mind when your dataset is huge : you'll pay the speed with more memory usage.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `aggregate`:

```
R> aggregate(Names ~ ID, data=tmp, FUN=paste, collapse=" | ")
          ID                                         Names
1 uc001aag.1        DKFZp686C24272 | DQ786314 | uc001aag.1
2 uc001aah.2 AK056232 | FLJ00038 | uc001aah.1 | uc001aah.2
3 uc001aai.1                                      AY217347
```

Comment: @rcs, this method works fine, but I have a very large dataset. is there a way to speed up the analysis? Thanks

Comment: Maybe parallelization with `ddply` from the `plyr` package: `ddply(tmp, .(ID), function(x) paste(x$Names, collapse=" | "), .parallel=TRUE)`

Comment: That code from the plyr package gives me this error: Loading required package: foreach
Error: foreach package required for parallel plyr operation
In addition: Warning message:
In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called 'foreach'

Comment: The `foreach` package is required. Furthermore, you have to register a parallel backend (i.e. `doMC`, not available for Windows platforms). See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588914/domc-vs-dosnow-vs-dosmp-vs-dompi-why-arent-the-various-parallel-backends-for-f/5621388#5621388

Comment: There was a file LOCK00 in the directory so the package foreach could not be downloaded. This fixed, but the analysis is still slow. The file contains 2 columns and 450000 rows.

Comment: @Lisann `tapply(tmp$Names,tmp$ID,paste,collapse=" | ")` is a bit faster, but anyway on this scale this is a job for a C code.

Comment: `tapply` can be modified to run in parallel using `snowfall`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'm gonna try it! =)

Comment: I'm not sure how much any of the parallelizing tricks will help much. The problem with ddply in this case (450,000 rows being merged into something like 200,000) is the combine step. The split step is probably not that expensive, and the paste shouldn't be too bad either. But ddply does an rbind repeatedly on the resulting little data.frames, which is a disaster because it has to re-optimize the string storage every time. (I think?) It may be better to use dlply, returning just the pasted string each time, then unlist() to collapse to a vector. Then paste back the ID names.