# Simple working example of ddply() in parallel on Windows

Tags: r, foreach, plyr

I've been searching around for a simple working example of using ddply() in parallel.  I've installed the "foreach" package, but when I call ddply( .parallel = TRUE) I get a warning that "No parallel backend registered")

Can someone provide a simple working example of using ddply in parallel?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a simple working example:

```
> df <- data.frame(val=1:10, ind=c(rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5)))
> library(doSNOW)
> registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(2, type = "SOCK"))
> system.time(print(ddply(df, .(ind), function(x) { Sys.sleep(2); sum(x) }, .parallel=FALSE)))
  ind V1
1   2 25
2   3 55
   user  system elapsed 
   0.00    0.00    4.01 
> system.time(print(ddply(df, .(ind), function(x) { Sys.sleep(2); sum(x) }, .parallel=TRUE)))
  ind V1
1   2 25
2   3 55
   user  system elapsed 
   0.02    0.00    2.02
```

Comment: Its really nice that ddply now supports this.  Thanks for digging this out of the graveyard!

Comment: @Shane Would the instructions be different for running it on Linux box?

Answer (score 7):

Have you registered a parallel backend to `foreach` ?

You may need to read up on use of `foreach` before you use it with `plyr`.

Comment: I looked at the function list but couldn't figure it out. I also looked at the vignette but could not find the terms "backend" nor "register" =)  I was hoping someone could just post a simple, complete working example.

Comment: @SFun28 - Have you checked out `vignette("gettingstartedMC")`?

Comment: Added "on Windows" to my title...seems like its possible on 32-bit with experimental multicore package, but not available on 64-bit.

Comment: The `foreach` package support several backends for parallisation; you may try `doSMP` on Windows as well as the older / simpler `snow` package via `doSnow`.  This is all non-trivial, but documented in `foreach` and related packages.

Comment: Adding to Dirk's comments, I've enjoyed using snowfall package (if you're into that sort of thing).

Comment: Roman, this is getting a little old. You don't need to parrot 'snowfall' each time someone asks for 'parallel with R' especially as snowfall, nice as it is, does not have a 'foreach' adapter -- at least AFAIK.

Comment: I assist @Roman. Snowfall on windows is just so easy to use. Almost no dealing with any initialization/registration!

Comment: All good and well, Henrik, but please show us how snowfall can help with 'ddply in parallel'.

Comment: And there comes the problem. As far as I know, no chance at all.

Comment: Per this post it seems like there will might be a fix in the next version of plyr.  I've emailed Hadley to get the scoop:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588914/domc-vs-dosnow-vs-dosmp-vs-dompi-why-arent-the-various-parallel-backends-for-f

Answer (score 6):

A. I've been communicating with Hadley and there are no plans in the immediate future to fix this bug.  The fix itself can be attempted by anyone.  Here are some tips I received from Hadley:

"It's relatively easy at the simplest level - you just need to pass a
.export argument to foreach.  Ideally, plyr would figure out what to
export automatically, but in the mean time, modifying .parallel to
take a list of arguments to foreach (instead of just T/F) would be a
big step.  Start with llply, and if you can get that working, it's
fairly trivial to get all the other functions working too."

B. I highly recommend snow and doSNOW to get parallel foreach to work on Windows.  The other parallel backends either: 1. don't support Windows  2. don't work on 64-bit Windows 3. are supposed to work on Windows but are too [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794266/error-attempting-dosmp-example).
snow/doSNOW was the the only solution that worked "out-of-the-box"

C. good luck!

Answer (score 4):

On Unix environments, you can do this using the doMC package and its function registerDoMC()

```
> registerDoMC()
> example <- ddply(..., .parallel=TRUE)
```

Comment: Question is explicitly about WINDOWS not Unix.